# Is it possible to use Nancy without ever scanning?

Tags: c#, nancy

We're developing an application and we've added Nancy to it to allow communication via HTTP with another application. However, Nancy's scanning for modules at startup is resulting in a significant performance penalty (more specifically, an interaction between Nancy's scan and [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T492392/assembly-reflectiononlyload-fails-due-to-thememanager-currentdomain-assemblyload) is resulting in a significant performance penalty).

Is there any way to completely disable Nancy's scanning and just manually register our custom types? The only class we have that implements a Nancy interface is a single module, so in theory it should just be that one module that needs to be registered, right?

Note that we're using the current 1.4.4 release of Nancy. If the 2.0 prerelease is necessary we'd be willing to try it out, but we would prefer to stick with 1.4.4 if reasonably possible.

Comment: All you need is here: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Bootstrapper

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can do an async startup of Nancy, in which case it shouldn't add to the startup pain that DevExpress is already causing.

Comment: @spender The *base* Nancy bootstrapper has calls to `AppDomainAssemblyTypeScanner` in non-virtual code. If I have to build my own bootstrapper from scratch just to register a single module, then we'll look for an alternative to Nancy.